# How to sort Windows by z-index?

Tags: wpf, z-index

If I'm enumerating windows in `Application.Current.Windows`, how can I tell, for any two windows, which one is "closer" (i.e. has greater z-index)?

Or, to say the same in other words, how can I sort those windows by z-index?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot get a Window's Z Order information from WPF so you must resort to Win32.

Something like this ought to do the trick:

```
var topToBottom = SortWindowsTopToBottom(Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>());
...

public IEnumerable<Window> SortWindowsTopToBottom(IEnumerable<Window> unsorted)
{
  var byHandle = unsorted.ToDictionary(win =>
    ((HwndSource)PresentationSource.FromVisual(win)).Handle);

  for(IntPtr hWnd = GetTopWindow(IntPtr.Zero); hWnd!=IntPtr.Zero; hWnd = GetWindow(hWnd, GW_HWNDNEXT)
    if(byHandle.ContainsKey(hWnd))
      yield return byHandle[hWnd];
}

const uint GW_HWNDNEXT = 2;
[DllImport("User32")] static extern IntPtr GetTopWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
[DllImport("User32")] static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint wCmd);
```

The way this works is:

1. It uses a dictionary to index the given windows by window handle, using the fact that in the Windows implementation of WPF, Window's PresentationSource is always HwndSource.
2. It uses Win32 to scan all unparented windows top to bottom to find the proper order.

Comment: And yes, sorry, this does require unmanaged code permission ("full trust").

Comment: I'll accept this nevertheless, as it's the only answer so far.

Comment: Could you please take a look at my latest question? I should really like to see your angle on the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642763/static-verification-of-bindings

Comment: I just wanted to add that this explanation might not be entirely accurate.
pInvoke.net points out that GetNextWindow is a macro, and we should instead call GetWindow
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetNextWindow.html
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindow.html
When I attempted to implement the above code in my .NET 4.0 WPF application it threw an exception when trying to call GetNextWindow stating it's not an available member, easily fixed by updating the method to GetWindow as defined by pInvoke.net
However the rest of the code works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Ah this was a really fun one:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();

public static Window ActiveWindow
{
    get
    {
        return HwndSource.FromHwnd(GetActiveWindow()).RootVisual as Window;
    }
}
```

It will give you the active window in your app (which is usually the foremost).

Comment: I think it is not whan he meant

Comment: Not only is it not what I meant, but it also requires Full Trust (as does any P/Invoke). And it might be even worth it, was it not easily achievable with the `Window.IsActive` property.