# WPF ContextMenu appearing on another screen

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on an application that runs on two monitors. I have two screens defined in Windows. In my WPF app, I have one window opening on Screen1 and a second window opening on Screen2. This second window has images each with a ContextMenu. On the click event of the image I call the method EnableLeftClick.

For some strange reason, the context menu appears in a random location on the first screen. I call this method because I needed to enable the context menu to open on the left mouse click. I tried using PlacementTarget, I tried using the ContextMenuService, but nothing is working. How can I force the ContextMenu to open exactly where the mouse is clicked? I tried setting the PlacementMode to Mouse and MousePoint, but always getting the same results. It appears on the other screen.

```
    private void EnableLeftClick(object sender)
    {
        var fe = sender as FrameworkElement;
        if (fe != null)
        {
            if (fe.ContextMenu == null) return;
            //fe.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = fe;
            //fe.ContextMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Bottom;
            //fe.ContextMenu.HorizontalOffset = 0;
            //fe.ContextMenu.VerticalOffset = 0;
            System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenuService.SetPlacement(fe, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Bottom);
            fe.ContextMenu.IsEnabled = true;
            fe.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
            fe.ContextMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```

What's worse is that the ContextMenu does not even close when I click elsewhere on the screen.

The ContextMenu is initialized in this method that executes when the Window opens. I Basically attach a different ContextMenu on several images.

```
    public void DoDynamicMenus()
    {
        m_menuService = GcsIocContainer.Instance.Container.Resolve<IMenuIntegrationService>();

        foreach (var menuConfiguration in m_menuService.GetMenuConfigurations())
        {
            foreach (var image in GetImageComponents<IAlsGraphic>(m_components))
            {
                if (menuConfiguration.RootImageName.Equals(image.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    var contextMenu = new System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu();
                    var fe = image.NativeObject as FrameworkElement;
                    foreach (var mi in menuConfiguration.GetRootMenuItems())
                    {
                        var menuItem = new System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem() { Header = mi.ItemCaption };
                        menuItem.Click += MenuItem_Click;
                        contextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem);
                        menuItem.Tag = mi;
                    }
                    fe.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
                    //fe.ContextMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    fe.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    contextMenu.IsEnabled = true;
                    contextMenu.IsOpen = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it always on the opposite screen? What happens when you start the app on the other monitor and then right click?

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861015/place-wpf-contextmenu-on-second-screen), don't know whether this will help you or not.

Comment: @Nobody I already saw that post. It is where I got the idea to try what you see in my code above. But nothing that it suggested works. Unless my parameters are wrong.

Comment: Where do you initialize he context menu for fe? is it in Xaml or code behind? can you show that piece of code please? Does the initialization gets called once or every time you try opening the context menu?

Comment: @OmarZaarour I added the method that initializes the contexte menu to my question.

Comment: Have you see this yet? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.placement(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I assume you un-commented the offset lines  when you tried the placement target to be mouse point?

Comment: @OmarZaarour I tried MousePoint and I uncommented the offset lines. I removed the PlacementTarget, and it is behaving closer to what I want. Thanks!

Comment: @OmarZaarour Unfortunately, the MousePoint does not work. When I click on the image and immedaitely move the mouse. The ContextMenu appears in the new location of the mouse.