# drop window in application into the main window like tab

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs, window

i am working on application with multiple windows, but i want to drop any window in the application into the main window like tab and can drop it back like window.

i have tried to used drop event in C# and MouseDown event in xaml but didn't work

so any idea how to do that?

Comment: i have found this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595618/drop-a-window-into-another-window ....the Answer by @nmaait it work but i can't drop back the tab like window!!!

Answer (score 0):

**You can't have a child "Window" within a window.**

You can have a child user control.

If you still want to have a child window, it would have to appear as a popup

`Or you can do a custom implementation like`

http://clipflair.codeplex.com/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/wpf-child-window/

### Updated Answer

`For docking window you can use third party tools like`

- [Devexpress](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/wpf/dock_windows/)
- [Avalon](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/)
- [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/docking.aspx)

`Or for a custom implementation you can try these examples`

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140209/Building-a-Docking-Window-Management-Solution-in-W
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/439873/Simple-Visual-Studio-like-Pane-Resizing-Docking-an
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22927/Multiple-Window-Interface-for-WPF
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18812/WPF-Docking-Library

Comment: thanks for your answer , but i am trying to implement docking to my windows So i can dock the window like tab

Comment: Check my updated answer i hope you find what you looking for