# Get Layer of Window Relative to Other Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, layer

In C# WPF, is there a way to determine a windows layer position (ie z-index)? I have a program that spawns new windows and I would like to save the order of layers.

So if I have three windows open, and Window 1 is in front of Window 2 and window 2 is in front of window 3, how can I get their position in relation to each other (or globally)?

Comment: So you're really talking about managing operating system windows (i.e., windows explorer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to resort to **Win32 interop**: **[How to sort Windows by z-index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473016/how-to-sort-windows-by-z-index)**

Comment: I ended up just tracking my windows by create order and then events such as `MouseDown` or `RequestBringIntoView` report that it is the topMost to the main application (static list of windows). When it reports its on top, I remove it from the list, then re-add it so that it is the last one on the list. Therefore, the last element is always the top, first is the bottom, etc.